# How to escape the output of an entire blade template from a parent template

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-blade, htmlspecialchars, laravel-6

I have a blade template that produces random XML using Faker. When I include the XML output inside an HTML5 template as such:

```
@extends('splash')

@section('content')

<pre>
    <!-- This is where the XML goes -->
    @yield('output') 
</pre>

@endsection
```

all my XML gets evaluated instead of displayed as is. I am only able to see the tag contents when I would like to be able to see the tag names and attributes. I would like to be able to escape the output of the XML generating template so something like:

```
@extends('splash')

@section('content')

<pre>
    {{@yield('output')}}
</pre>

@endsection
```

Except of course that doesn't work because PHP interprets this as a yield statement prepended with a suppress errors operators instead of the blade directive. So basically what I would like to know is what the raw php equivalent of the @yield directive is.

Comment: What does your splash template look like? Please consider adding it to the question

Comment: It's just HTML5 boilerplate with a content section. I don't think it's really relevant to the question at all. Other than perhaps that this isn't XHTML

Comment: To include a template in another, the template which you extend must have matching sections. That is, if you use `@section('content')` in your child template, you must have `@section('content')` and `@show` in your parent template.

Comment: The issue is not that I'm not getting the output, it's that the output is XML code that I would like to display as XML code brackets and quotes and all. Instead my tags get evaluated by the browser and I only see the contents. I'll try to edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: I don't know about a named section, but you can use `{{view('my.view.name')->render()}}` to show the escaped output of an entire view.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

```
@extends('splash')

@section('content')

<pre>
    {{View::getSection('output')}}
</pre>

@endsection
```

Did the trick for me